# Is this casting?

Tags: c

Sorry for not even knowing what to title this, but here goes.

Suppose I have:

```
char Fred[] = "1234 Evergreen Terrace";
char Pete[] = "4567 State Street";
char Mark[] = "123 North Street";

char Name[32];
gets(Name);
```

instead of writing:

```
if(strcmp(name,"Fred")==0); 
  printf("You live at %s\n",Fred);
else if(strcmp(name,"Pete")==0); 
  printf("You live at %s\n",Pete);
else if(strcmp(name,"Mark")==0); 
  printf("You live at %s\n",Mark);
```

Isn't there a way to skip all the strcmps() by writing:

```
printf("You live at %s\n",<SOMETHING_HERE>Name)
```

My needs are more complex but the above simple example should get me going. It's been nearly 15 years since I learned about it but I just can't recall.
Thanks in advance!
Dan

Comment: **NEVER EVER** use "gets". Since it does not allow you to pass in the size of the buffer, it is impossible for "gets" to be implemented in a secure fashion. The function "gets" is a sure-fire way to give your application a buffer-overflow vulnerability, so stay clear of it.

Comment: Your code looks like C, but is tagged C++. Are you looking for a C or C++ solution?

Answer (score 11):

- Use an std::map of string--> string.
- Take a string from the input
- if it is in the map, print it

Sample:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::map< std::string, std::string > MapType;
    MapType names;

    names.insert(std::make_pair("Fred", "1234 Evergreen Terrace"));
    names.insert(std::make_pair("Pete", "4567 State Street"));
    names.insert(std::make_pair("Mark", "123 North Street"));

    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    MapType::iterator it = names.find(input);
    if(it != names.end())
        std::cout << input  << "lives at: " << it->second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use the map[] to insert the values it looks more intuitive: names["Fred"] = "1234 Evergreen Terrace"

Comment: Because using insert as opposed to [] operator to add elements to a map is more efficient. It saves three function calls: creating a temporary string object, an assignment operator call, and a destructor call to the temporary string object.

Answer (score 3):

Look [maps in the STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

```
using namespace std;
map<string, string> lookup( map<string,string> );
lookup["Fred"] = string( "1234 Evergreen Terrace" );
...
string name( "Fred" ); // or other values 

cout << "You live at " << lookup[name];
//Alternative using find to deal with missing name

map<string,string>::iterator address( lookup.find( name ) );   //Edited to use find
if ( address != map.end() ) { 
  cout << "You live at " << lookup[name];
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add something to handle the case where the name isn't in the map

Comment: And on the contrary to Mark, don't write `using namespace std;` but do write `using std::map, std::string, std::cout;`... importing all the namespace symbols in the current namespace is really not necessary.

Comment: As David Oneill implied, using the find() method of std::map is often better.  Otherwise, you'll end up adding names you look up that aren't already there.

Comment: I did this to make the code example shorter and clearer. I note that "C++ coding standards" by Alexandrescu and Sutter says "You can and should use namespace using directives liberally in your implementation files after #include directoives and feel good about it.  In real code I have tended to use std:: perhaps I should use it less - depends on how different the classes/methods are. map string swap tend to be not classes I would put in another namespace

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a map.  A data structure that will map your names -> addresses.

Try making a structure like this:

```
struct person {
    char name[32];
    char address[256];
}
```

Then create an array of person structures:

```
struct person[] = {
    {"fred", "1234 Evergreen Terrace"},
    {"pete", "4567 State Street"},
    {"mark", "123 North Street"}
};

int numberOfPeople = 3;
```

Then when you need to find one you can search it this way:

```
for(int index = 0; index < numberOfPeople; index++) {
    if(!strcmp(person[index].name, name)) {
        printf("You live at %s.\n");
    }
}
```

Obviously there are many more advanced ways of doing this.  I'd suggest reading up on classes and hashmaps.  A class is a more advanced version of a structure that allows you to do all sorts of neat stuff.  A hash map is a data structure that uses something called a hash function to use your string as a key that finds the correct address.

Or rather than learning about exactly how maps work and making your own, you could always be lazy and just use std::map ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could store the names and addresses in an associative container such as an STL map with the name being the key and the address being the value.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> people;

// ... Add the entries to the map here ...
people["Fred"] = "1234 Evergreen Terrace";
people["Pete"] = "4567 State Street";
people["Mark"] = "123 North Street";
```

Then the single printf:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator iter = people.find(Name);
if(iter != people.end())
    printf("You live at %s\n", iter->second);
```

Note that you need to check for the case where the name does not already exist within the map - e.g. using find() as shown above.

Comment: This, too, uses unchecked input for a lookup in the map.

Comment: sbi - was capturing that via text but have made it more explicit by adding the check to the code.

Comment: @Stephen: Sorry that I missed this in the text. But I think this is better now. However, note that now you're doing _two_ lookups instead of one. I removed my down-vote nevertheless.

Comment: @sbi - indeed I was. Have removed the duplicate lookup.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there a way to skip all the `strcmp()`?

In C++, this is spelled `std::map`:

```
std::map<string, string> address_map;

address_map[Fred] = "1234 Evergreen Terrace";
address_map[Pete] = "4567 State Street";
address_map[Mark] = "123 North Street";

std::map<string,string>::const_iterator it = address_map.find(name);
if( it == address_map.end() ) doh();
std::cout << "You live at " << it->second << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd want to implement some sort of dictionary (map) structure, where the name user inputs would be a key. You'd map it as string->string and if the key is in the map, then output the other string.

There are many ways of implementing this, you can do it by hand or you can look up std::map.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged C++. In C++ you can just take a standrad implementation of associative array and prepare your data as follows

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
...
std::map<std::string, std::string> name2address;
name2address["Fred"] = "1234 Evergreen Terrace";
name2address["Pete"] = "4567 State Street";
name2address["Mark"] = "123 North Street";
```

Then, once you have the requested name

```
char Name[32];
gets(Name);
// I leave it as is, but using `gets` is always nasty. And you might be much 
// better off with a 'std::string' instead in this case
```

you can find the addreess and print it

```
std::string address = name2address[Name];
// Add a check for whether it actually exists

printf("You live at %s\n", address.c_str());
// Again, I leave `printf` as is
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complicated the rest of what you're dealing with is, you should consider putting these into a class.  A class can keep a name and address associated with each other as well.

```
class person
{
  char[32] name;
  char[32] address;
  /* whatever else you need to know about the people */

  /* whatever functions you'd need to run on them */
}
```

then create a map of these classes, again using the name

```
std::map<string,person> person_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question C++, and in the C++ STL library you can use the map container to map names to addresses in your case.  Some example code for your problem below, using the STL string instead of char arrays, which you may find preferable:

```
// Set up your map
#include <map>
#include <string>
using std;

map<string, string> myMap;

myMap["Fred"] = "1234 Evergreen Terrace";
myMap["Pete"] = "4567 State Street";
myMap["Mark"] = "123 North Street";
```

And once you have your map set up, and you've read the user input into a string variable name, you would use something like:

```
if(myMap.find(name) != myMap.end())
{
    printf("You live at %s\n", myMap[name].c_str());
}
else
{
    printf("I don't know where you live");
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Casting is the direct, unambigous, conversion from one thing to another thing enforced (mostly) at compile time. There's:

- Casting of built-in types that can be legally converted to each-other (**static_cast**). An example to this is int->double conversion:

  double d = 5.0;
  int i = static_cast(d);
- Telling the compiler to treat the data at address X like a different type (**reinterpret_cast**). This is similar to a union.

  struct Message
  {
      int header;
      int contents;
      //...
  };

  char* myDataBuffer;
  Message* interpretedAsAMessage = reinterpret_cast(myDataBuffer).
- There's legal casting up/down an inheritance hierarchy (**dynamic_cast**):

  class Base
  {
  };

  class Derrived : public Base
  {
  };

  Derrived* d = new Derrived();
  Base* b = dynamic_cast(d)
  // b will be null if types aren't related.
- There's removing constness from a variable to be able to manipulate it (**const_cast**)

  const int size = 5;
  int& sizeRef = const_cast(size);
  size++;
- Then you'll also see the C-style cast, which is more ambigous, and doesn't tell you or the compiler explicitly what kind of cast is happening.

  double d = 5.0;
  int i = (int)(d);

There' In your case ou expect the resultant type to be formatted a specific way. In the above examples, the result is unambigous and clear. There's no way to specify how a resultant string would be formatted in the above examples. You need to take an approach similar to what you have or what thers have posted.